# `Rug()` function in `ggplot2`

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This question is somehow related to a previous question of mine, but with a different goal. I have the following code

```
x<-c(seq(1,20,1))
y<-runif(20)
rugp<-c(runif(50,0,20))
plot(x,y,type="b")
rug(rugp,col="red")
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

I would like to do the same but with `ggplot`. Is there an equivalent function to `rug()` in `ggplot2`? I tried the `geom_rug()` option but it doesn't work, as it doesn't let me add my own points to rug. Thank you!

Comment: There's an exact equivalent called `geom_rug` ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just updated my question with that option but it doesn't let me add my own points to rug :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @csgroen, `geom_rug` is the equivalent of `rug` function.

However, your `rug` vector has a different length from `x` and `y`, so you have to specify pass some arguments into the `aes` to ge tthe same figure than the one you get in `base r plot`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x, y)
df_rug <- data.frame(rugp)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_rug(data = df_rug, aes(x = rugp, y = Inf), color = "red", sides = "b")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: I see! That was precisely the error message I got with `ggplot` because the length of `rug`, is different from the length of `x`! That solved then my problem!

Comment: By the way, what does the option `group=1` in `aes()`?

Comment: My mistake, it is useless here. I thought it could have been necessary for `geom_line` to indicate you need consider all values a single group but you can remove it. I'm editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm just making a slightly simpler functional answer:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x,y)) +
    geom_rug(aes(x = rugp), color = "red")
```

No need to make a table for the rug, I think.

Comment: Ah, that's a perfect alternative too :-) Didn't think about removing the options from `ggplot()` and putting them inside of `geom_line()` :-)